# Jquery selector - disable inputs excluding specific input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable all inputs in the form excluding a hidden input with the name **__RequestVerificationToken**

I tried

```js
$('form :input:not(name=__RequestVerificationToken)').prop('disabled', true);
```

but its not working, any help would be appreciated.

---

Apologies, I missed some details -- see below test

```
<form>
  <input value="disable me" />
  <input value="disable me" />  
  <input value="disable me" />
  <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="not me" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button>Disable All Except __RequestVerificationToken</button>
</form>
```

```js
$("button").on("click", () => {
   $('form :input').prop('disabled', true); this works
  // $('form :input:not(name=__RequestVerificationToken)').prop('disabled', true); // this not
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/fxz3em8b/2/

Comment: What exactly does *"not working"* mean? Where is the runnable [mcve]? Also did you try quoting the name value in the selector?

Comment: `:input`? i think you mean just `input` as input is not a Pseudo-class

Comment: also, jquery has its own `.not()` function to use. read more about that here: https://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: @RamondeVries jQuery has a `:input` pseudo class as well as a `:not()` selector also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `[]` for the attribute selector

```js
$("button").on("click", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();  
   $('form :input:not([name=__RequestVerificationToken])').prop('disabled', true); 
                   // ^^    missing braces           ^^
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input value="disable me" />
  <input value="disable me" />  
  <input value="disable me" />
  <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="not me" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button>Disable All Except __RequestVerificationToken</button>
</form>
```